# Prevent Magento from rolling back custom table entries

Tags: event-observer, magento-1.6, payment-methods, payment-gateway, transaction

I am using **third-party integration for on-site credit/debit card payment functionality.**

With a purpose to audit transactions and as well as for order status flow customization, I need to save customer and payment related details in custom table.

But **whenever, any error is detected from third-party gateway**(i.e. Insufficient balance) while placing an order and thus invoking authorize/capture request to third party gateway, **Magento rollbacks transaction including my custom table audit entries**. 
I know, reverting transaction to its begin stage is a perfect thing for data integrity and according to standard Magento architecture, but I just **do not want to get my custom entries in my custom table to get rolled back.**

How do I prevent Magento from doing this?

Can observer(dispatchEvent) be used to audit data as I am not sure if observer actually bypasses the standard transaction rollback call?

**UPDATE**

1. dispatching custom using `Mage::dispatchEvent`, is of no help
2. direct query(core/resource) to insert records will also get rolled
   back in case of any error/exception before order successfully gets placed.

Comment: Please take your time to accept an answer if it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Everything in between starting and rolling back the transaction will be rolled back as well, so you have the choice to either save your custom data before or after the transaction. Unfortunately the "save_before" and "save_after" events are triggered within the transaction and the "commit_after" event is only triggered after a successful commit. There is no such thing as a "rollback _after" event.

What should work is the `sales_model_service_quote_submit_failure` event (See [`Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php)).

You can observe this together with `sales_model_service_quote_submit_after` with the same observer (both receive the same parameters and always only one of them is dispatched)

Comment: I will try your solution for sure...